# getting trigger id jqm

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

Given:

```
$('#test').jqm({
  ajax: 'action/?id=1' + '&triggerId=' + ???
  trigger: '#no1, #no2'
});
```

Is there a way to pass id of which trigger fired? And is there a better way to pass id and trigger id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$(this)`, references the item triggered (or should).

So `$(this).attr('id');` would get its id.